# mongodb returns incorrect type of a key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im using node.js+express+mongodb+mongoose, trying to retrieve user from database by custom ids, page returns back completely empty due to incorrect datatype of id value, here is some part of my code:

```
var User = new Schema({
  name: String , 
  email: String ,
  id: Number,
  role: String
});
var userModel = mongoose.model('User', User);
var person = new userModel();

function loaduser(req, res, next) {
  userModel.find({}, req.params.id, function(err, user){
    if (user){
      req.user = user;
      console.log(user);
      next();
    }
  })
  console.log(typeof req.params.id);
};

//personal page route
app.get('/user/:id', loaduser, function(req, res){
  res.render('show', { users: req.user });
});
```

and then this returns in console:

```
string
{ _id: 5012aa222c2d4d5876c5acd0,
    email: 'alex@mail.com',
    id: '0',
    name: 'alex',
    role: 'admin' },
```

even though i declared type of id as *Number* it gets back as *String*.
Any suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `find` call isn't quite right.  The first parameter should be your query document and since you're looking for one document you should use `findOne` instead.  You also need to convert `req.params.id` to a number:

```
userModel.findOne({ id: Number(req.params.id) }, function(err, user){
```

If you still see a problem with `id` coming back as a string, it must be a string in the collection.

Comment: essentially all i want to do is render a personal page for each user that has an id (and not an objectId), so if i understand this correctly - i need to call "find" instead of "findOne". convert req.params.id seems to be good idea though, but if i just change findOne to find - page refuses to render, its just freezes.. Anyway, thanks a lot !!

Comment: If you're looking to retrieve the one document with the user's `id` you want to use `findOne`.  If you use `find` then the second parameter to your `find` callback is an array of user documents, not just one.

Comment: page freezes. and in few minutes - "no data received"

Comment: @user1559803 I could see that happening if `user` is null in your callback (i.e. user not found) as you don't have an `else` clause to handle that case .  Your middleware always needs to either call `next();` or send a response.

Comment: thank you for solving two troubles by once :) you're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

`req.params.id` seems to be wrong in

`userModel.find({}, req.params.id, function(err, user){`

---

It should be

`userModel.find({}, { id: parseInt(req.params.id) }, function(err, user){`